# How can i user kettle connect to phoenix

Tags: kettle, apache-phoenix

I just set the config like that:
http://talat.uyarer.com/post/121179803796/how-to-connect-hbase-using-apache-phoenix-from

but it does not work, and it show me the error:
[image: my error image]

Answer (score 0):

I never used apache-phoenix, but in front of this type of error I'd first check if the driver is in the lib (I guess it is), then on the database connection parameters on the left panel). According to the error, I'd start with the `Advanced/Prefered Schema name`, and the `Option/Parameter` with a parameter name you have to drill from the apache-phoenix documentation.

Comment: yeah. I set the drivers in the lib,and I use the same url and drivers  in squirrel-sql and it does work, so i have some confuse about that.  and now i am trying the old version to check .